# How to use IntegerRangeField in Django template

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm using [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) with [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/). I have a model with a [IntegerRangeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#integerrangefield).

When using `{{ field }}` in template the result is (for example) `NumericRange(2, 8, '[)')`

How can I get the range numbers in my template?

I tried `{{ field.0 }}` and `{{ field.1 }}` but got no output (I expected `2` and `8` respectively).

Comment: Try out {{ field.upper }} and {{ field.lower}}.

Comment: @rajkris, great thanks! please make it as an answer so that I can accept it

Comment: Glad to hear that. Thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try out `{{ field.upper }}` and `{{ field.lower}}`.

Answer (score 4):

Use *upper* and *lower* to get range from object of [**`NumericRange`**](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.NumericRange).

```
In [5]: from psycopg2.extras import NumericRange

In [6]: a = NumericRange(2, 8, '[)')

In [7]: a.lower
Out[7]: 2

In [8]: a.upper
Out[8]: 8
```